# errors while committing the repository in sourcetree, Git window client

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am new to bitbucket, git and sourcetree. i created a repository on bitbucket, then i installed the sourcetree client for win 7, then i clone that repository with my local desktop folder, then i placed a file in the local folder, now when i try to commit the changes, sourcetree give me following errors.

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false commit -q -F C:\Users\shahjahan_khokher\AppData\Local\Temp\vrkvrvyu.uba
>
> *** Please tell me who you are.
>
> Run
>
> git config --global user.email "you@example.com"   git config
>   --global user.name "Your Name"
>
> to set your account's default identity. Omit --global to set the
>   identity only in this repository.
>
> fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got
>   'shahjahan_khokher@shahjahan_khokh.(none)')
>
> Completed with errors, see above.

how can i resolve this issue and do a successful commit and push.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got the solution for above mentioned problem, with the help of my friend
, Solution is

1. First get the Git Bash command line in ur system by installing Git from [Download Git for Windows](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+Git+and+Mercurial)
2. Then open Git Bash from start manu - Git - Git Bash and run these commands

> ```
> git config --global user.email "you@example.com" 
>
> git config --global user.name "Your Name"
> ```

Now try to commit again, problem will be resolved.

Comment: git config --global user.email "you@example.com"   only type this line, it works for me , (UBUNTU 14.10)

Answer (score 31):

The easiest way to solve the issue with your identity without using Git Bash is to set it in SourceTree directly: -

1. Got to menu: Tools -> Options
2. On the general tab fill in the Full Name and Email address fields
3. Click the OK button
4. Commit your files :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

Simple and precise.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+Git+and+Mercurial

Comment: Just linking to another site is not in the spirit of stackoverflow. Rather explicitly type the information here. You can still include the link.